# Eclipse/Luna displays previous repository location

Tags: eclipse, subversive

I have a problem with Eclipse/Luna (CDT) that's driving me nuts:

In the project explorer panel Eclipse displays the old repository server name/path.

The repository has been moved to another server. All SVN operations work correctly, 'svn info' both on the command line and from Eclipse/Project properties/SVN info display the correct server name/path etc. It is only on the project label in the project explorer.
The version number is displayed and updated correctly.
I have checked out the complete project into a new directory but the problem persists.

What do I have to do to make Eclipse display the correct SVN server name?

Comment: Check the 'Location Properties' in the SVN Repositories view to see if you are using a custom label

Comment: Ha! Yes, this custom label was set, but on the old repository location (which actually was linked to the new repository now). Changed this, now it looks okay! :-) Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe you want to post this as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the 'SVN Repositories' view. Right click on the repository and select the 'Location Properties'. You probably have a 'custom label' set which refers to the old repository name, change this to the new name.